# Reveal Modal Popup Call on DIV

Tags: jquery, html

I have little problem i am using [Reveal Modal Popup](http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin) my issue is that i want to call this on only div not on hyperlink of `<a> tag` and also not on page load how could i change that.

in reveal.js here is the code:

```
    $('div[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
    $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
});
```

**here is the complete reveal.js** [reveal.js](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48992367/AppzVenture/extra/jquery.reveal.js)

and on html here is the code:

```
<a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="fade">
        Fade and Pop
    </a>    

    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
        <h1>Reveal Modal Goodness</h1>
        <p>This is a default modal in all its glory, but any of the styles here can easily be changed in the CSS.</p>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
```

Only want to call in div because i want to use this on php some when event occur(s).

Comment: Its work my question is that how does its open on div only not when the click happen i just want to open no call back etc...

Comment: you mean you want to open the modal by clicking a **DIV** instead of an *anchor*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solutions:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myModal').reveal();
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').reveal();
});
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myModal').reveal();
});
</script>
```

OR

If you had trouble getting this to work on a page using other .js libraries where JQuery NoConflict was being used -- in that case try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { $('#myModal').reveal(); });
```

Comment: Thats work thanks last example works !! i am using jQuery No Conflict